# Plotting a heatmap (kernel density) using geopandas + geoplot crashes session

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, kernel-density, geoplot

I recently posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69082127/plot-heatmap-kdeplot-with-geopandas/69089479#69089479) on how to plot a heatmap using geopandas. I was recommended to use `geoplot.kdeplot()`, but passing a `projection` crashes my session.

Suppose I have the following data stored in `df_points` and `df_map` respectively:

```
> print(df_points)
        PointID                     geometry
0     204403876  POINT (-101.66700 21.11670)
1     204462769  POINT (-101.66700 21.11670)
2     144407530  POINT (-101.66700 21.11670)

> print(df_map)
     PolyID                                           geometry
0     01001  POLYGON ((-102.10641 22.06035, -102.10368 22.0...
1     01002  POLYGON ((-102.05189 22.29144, -102.05121 22.2...
2     01003  POLYGON ((-102.68569 22.09963, -102.69087 22.0...
```

This is what I tried, but according to [this tutorial](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html#kdeplot), I should pass a `projection` to the heatmap.

```py
# Import geoplot
import geoplot
import geoplot.crs as gcrs

# Plot points
ax = geoplot.kdeplot(df_points, shade=True, alpha=0.7)
# Plot polygons
geoplot.polyplot(df_map, ax=ax)
```

[image: bad projection]

However, if I add `projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea()`, my session crashes:

```py
# Plot heatmap
ax = geoplot.kdeplot(df_points, cmap='Reds', shade=True,
                     projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea()) # This crashes my session ):
# Add polygons
geoplot.polyplot(df_map, ax=ax)
```

> python3: geos_ts_c.cpp:3991: int GEOSCoordSeq_getSize_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, const geos::geom::CoordinateSequence*, unsigned int*): Assertion `0 != cs' failed.

How can I pass `projection=gcrs.AlbersEqualArea()` and avoid the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm commenting on a previous question: I've just run the example in the official geoplot reference with Colab and experienced a similar crash. After some research I found that the crash was caused by shaply and uninstalled and reinstalled it and the graphs were displayed as per the reference. Please give it a try.

```
pip uninstall shapely
pip install shapely --no-binary shapely
```

Here are the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111684/geometry-must-be-a-point-or-linestring-error-using-cartopy) that helped me

Comment: The actual [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ECIAJHPicN50TMt2ceg49ZwIaywA9O_u?usp=sharing) can be found here. Please refer to the If you confirm, we will remove it.